# Confused by DOM Event Listeners

Tags: javascript, html, css, dom

I'm sorry if this is a simple question, but I am having a hard time with some javascript.

```js
function login() {
    var lgin = document.getElementById("logIn");
    lgin.style.display = "block";
    lgin.style.position = "fixed";
    lgin.style.width = "100%";
    lgin.style.height = "100%";
    lgin.style.paddingTop = "15px";
}

var lgButton = document.getElementById("openRooms");
lgButton.addEventListener("click", login, false);
```

```html
<p><a href="#" id="openRooms">Log In</a></p>

<section id="logIn">
  <div class="form-style-6">
    <h3>Log In</h3>
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="field1" placeholder="Name" />
      <input type="email" name="field2" placeholder="Email Address" />
      <input type="password" name="field3" placeholder="Password" />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
      </div>
</section>
```

My problem here is that the javascript that I have written out does not work.

I'm wondering if one of you could possibly help me with this.

Comment: Looks OK, did you open the console (F12) and check for errors, you probably added the script before the elements in the DOM, try moving the script tag down to right **before** `</body>`.

Comment: Also #logIn also has the CSS property of (display: none;)

Comment: Change `.padding-top` to `.paddingTop`.

Comment: ^^ and that's the error you'd see in the web console ("ReferenceError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment" sinc eyou can't assign to an expression, and `lgin.style.padding-top` is `lgin.style.padding` `-` `top`). As adeneo says, you can open the web console via F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I on most browsers.

Comment: Oh, didn't spot the hyphen, that would indeed be an error in the console.

Comment: @HTMLNoob, you can add all these styles to one class and try setAttribute('class', 'className');

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS:

```
#logIn.selected {
  display:block;
  position:fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  paddingTop: 15%;
}
```

JS:

```
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
     function login() {
       document.getElementById("logIn").setAttribute("class", "selected");
     }

     var lgButton = document.getElementById("openRooms");
     lgButton.addEventListener("click", login, false);
  });
```

Comment: You can also use the `.className` property, like this `element.className = 'someClass'`, this is okay, but it gets difficult once an element has a number of classes applied to it and you need to check or change them. However, even better than `className`, you get a `classList` member, which can check-for, toggle, add and remove from the list of classes that an element may have. Doing so thusly: `elem.classList.contains(className);` and `elem.classList.toggle(className);` and `elem.classList.add(className);` and finally, `elem.classList.remove(className);` - enjoy! :)

Comment: Yes. this also nice way !

Answer (score 1):

add your event listeners inside window load event callback

```
window.addEventListener("load",function(){
  var lgButton = document.getElementById("openRooms");
  lgButton.addEventListener("click", login, false);    
},false);
```